# How to get all the words around a word within a fixed proximity

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing

I have texts of variable size (1k-100k characters). I want to get all the words around a given word within fixed proximity. The given word is obtained from a regex so I have the start and the end of the word.

For example:

```
PROXIMITY_LENGTH = 10  # the fixed proximity
my_text = 'some random words 1123 word1 word123 a'
start, stop = re.search(r'\b1123\b', my_text).span()

print(f'start = {start}, stop = {stop}')
print(my_text[start - PROXIMITY_LENGTH: start]) 
print(my_text[stop: stop + PROXIMITY_LENGTH])

left_limit = my_text[:start - PROXIMITY_LENGTH].rfind(' ') + 1
right_limit = stop + PROXIMITY_LENGTH + my_text[stop + PROXIMITY_LENGTH:].find(' ') 

print('\n')
print(my_text[left_limit: start]) 
print(my_text[stop: right_limit])
```

output:

```
start = 18, stop = 22
dom words 
 word1 wor


random words 
 word1 word123
```

The issues are at the limit, the fixed proximity can cut the last word(from right/left limit).
In the above example, I tried to come with a solution, but my solution fails if I have tabs or newline as delimitator between words, ex:

for `my_text = 'some\trandom words 1123 word1 word123 a'` with my solution I got on the left side: `some   random words` which is wrong.

Any help is appreciated! Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the answers are really helpful, but I come with a simple approach, to take all the words within proximity except those from the limit, so if the proximity limit will cut a word that word will not be taken into consideration. This approach is more efficient:

```
text = ' some random\twords 123 123 - 123 some other random words.' 
regex = r'\b\d((\s*|\s*-\s*)\d){8}\b'
PROXIMITY_LENGTH = 10
REGEX_NO_START_END_WORD = r'\W.+\W'

start, end = re.search(regex, text).span()

left_limit = start - PROXIMITY_LENGTH
if left_limit < 0:
    left_limit = 0

right_limit = end + PROXIMITY_LENGTH
if right_limit > len(text):
    right_limit = len(text)

text_within_proximity = text[left_limit: right_limit]
re.search(REGEX_NO_START_END_WORD, text_within_proximity, flags=re.DOTALL).group()
```

output:

```
'\twords 123 123 - 123 some '
```

Comment: right_limit  it is used in slicing the text, so  there is no need to subtract 1

Answer (score 3):

Instead of looking at characters, I will look for words. In that way, you will say, find my target and add N words before and after it:

```
PROXIMITY_LENGTH = 2  # the fixed proximity
my_text = 'some random words 1123 word1 word123 a \t1123 this too will work'.split()

found = [x.find('1123') for x in my_text]

k = [' '.join(my_text[index-PROXIMITY_LENGTH:index+PROXIMITY_LENGTH+1]) for index, item in enumerate(found) if item == 0]


print(k)

# ['random words 1123 word1 word123', 'word123 a 1123 this too']
```

Using regex, we can replace `found` variable with;

```py
found = []
for x in my_text:
    if re.search(r'\b1123\b',x):
        found.append(0)
    else:
        found.append(-1)
```

The only think I do is split the string to a list :)

Comment: The issue of using words(in the way that you described)  is the regex, is not just one word(space and tabs also included), this way I mentioned that I know the start and the end of the word in the text. Thx for the answer! (I  upvoted)

Comment: Thanks! We can make regex work in many cases. Can you share hardest case examples with regex you are after, and I will try solve it.

Comment: Ok, the hardest  will be like: my_text = ' some random words 123   123  -  123   some other random words.'  regex = r'\b\d((\s*|\s*-\s*)\d) {9}\b)'

Comment: regex =r'\b\d((\s*|\s*-\s*)\d){8}\b'

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by simply expanding your regex pattern to include the desired number of words around the target match:

```
L = 2 # using a proximity length of just 2 for demo
my_text = 'some random words 1123 word1 word123 a'
print(re.search(r'(\w+\s+){{0,{0}}}\b1123\b(\s+\w+){{0,{0}}}'.format(L), my_text).group())
```

This outputs:

```
random words 1123 word1 word123
```

Comment: Thx you for your answer! You are looking for words instead of looking at characters!(upvote)

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to get the proximity according to signs (distance from the start/stop) and you wish to get to hole word once the proximity distance ended up in the middle of the word.

In this case I would suggest to search the first None character that is not a letter neither a number.
Try the following code:

```
import re
import string

def get_left_limit(left_string, proximity, right_limit=False):
    if proximity >= len(left_string):
        return len(left_string)

    start_diff = 0
    for letter in reversed(list(left_string[:-proximity])):
        if letter not in (string.ascii_letters + string.digits):
            break
        start_diff += 1
    return proximity + start_diff

def get_right_limit(right_string, proximity):
    if proximity >= len(right_string):
        return len(right_string)

    end_diff = 0
    for letter in list(right_string[proximity:]):
        if letter not in (string.ascii_letters + string.digits):
            break
        end_diff += 1
    return proximity + end_diff


PROXIMITY_LENGTH = 10  # the fixed proximity


# example 1
print('Example: 1')
my_text = 'some random words 1123 word1 word123 a'
start, stop = re.search(r'\b1123\b', my_text).span()
print(f'start = {start}, stop = {stop}')
#
left_proximity = get_left_limit(my_text[:start], PROXIMITY_LENGTH)
right_proximity = get_right_limit(my_text[stop:], PROXIMITY_LENGTH)
print(my_text[start - left_proximity:start])
print(my_text[stop:stop + right_proximity])

# example 2
print()
print('Example: 2')
my_text = 'some\trandom words 1123 word1 word123 a'
start, stop = re.search(r'\b1123\b', my_text).span()
print(f'start = {start}, stop = {stop}')
#
left_proximity = get_left_limit(my_text[:start], PROXIMITY_LENGTH)
right_proximity = get_right_limit(my_text[stop:], PROXIMITY_LENGTH)
print(my_text[start - left_proximity:start])
print(my_text[stop:stop + right_proximity])
```

The above code will result with:

```
Example: 1
start = 18, stop = 22
random words 
 word1 word123

Example: 2
start = 18, stop = 22
random words 
 word1 word123
```

Answer (score 1):

- create a list indexes of word separators ('\s+')
- use the found word `.span()` to find your start/end position of the searched substring in the list
- take the desired number of items left and right from the above mentioned position will give you left and right "limits" in the text

Code:

```
text = ' some random\twords 123 123 - 123 some other random words.' 
regex = r'\b\d((\s*|\s*-\s*)\d){8}\b'
neighbor = 2

search_b, search_e = re.search(regex, text).span()
splitted = [(0,0)] + [m.span(0) for m in re.finditer('\s+', text)] + [(len(text), len(text))]
left_limit, right_limit = None, None
for ix, (beg, end) in enumerate(splitted):
    if left_limit is None and beg >= search_b:
        left_limit = splitted[max(0, ix - 1 - neighbor)][1]
    if right_limit is None and search_e <= end:
        right_limit = splitted[min(len(splitted)-1, ix + neighbor)][0]
print(text[left_limit:right_limit])


>>>
random  words 123 123 - 123 some other
```